# Sql server 2012 date comparison with format function not returning as expected

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Data from my database:

[image]

As you can see I have several rows with column `NEWS_DPU` populated.

I don't understand why this query:

```
select * from canews
where format(news_dpu, 'mm.dd.yyyy') <= format(convert(datetime, '12.01.2016'), 'mm.dd.yyyy')
```

is returning only this:

[image]

Only one row is returned from query, but there should be several of them with `NEWS_DPU` smaller or equal to december 1st 2016. Am I missing something?

**SOLUTION:**

As John pointed out, `MM` means month and `mm` means minutes.
I've just changed `mm` to `MM` and everything is fine.

Comment: Can you please explain why you're using `<=` together with two dates formatted as month-day-year? It will return a quite odd ordering, are you sure you're using the right format for this? Why can't you simply use normal datetime comparison directly?

Comment: In other words, why do you want 4th of May 2016 to come before 4th of July 2015?

Comment: Or, in relation to your specific query, why do you want 1st of August 2017 to come before 1st of December 2016? Text-wise, `08.01.2017` is less than `12.01.2016` because `0` comes before `1` (the first digit of each).

Comment: If you can format the date in `yyyy-mm-dd` in application life will be so much easier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First change your format to MM which is month while mm is minutes

But I really think you want

```
select * from canews
where news_dpu <= convert(datetime, '12.01.2016',103)
```

Comment: Is casing also important with day and year?

Comment: @FrenkyB yes it is.  DD will return "DD" and YYYY would return "YYYY"

Comment: your first answer - 'MM.dd.yyyy' has completely solved my problem.

Comment: @FrenkyB Happy to help, but my concert is that you are doing string comparisons with a MM.DD.YYYY format  12.01.2015 IS NOT < 01.01.2015 .  Just for fun try Select min(S) From (Select S= '12.01.2015' Union All Select S= '01.01.2016') A

Comment: Thanks John, you are right. I guess correct way is convert to date and then make date comparisons.